# Prevent flicker when changing focus. Detecting focus change, rather than focus in/focus out

Tags: javascript

I currently have a page that is rendered with tech I won't delve in for now, because it's irrelevant I believe.

In this page, I have a bunch of controls (simple text inputs).
There's also a side panel where the help is displayed.
When the user focuses on one of the controls, the side panel shows the help for that control. When no control is in focus (as when the page is first accessed), a default help is shown.

I handle this using focusin/focusout events. When one of the control ids is focused in, I display their help.

To restore the help at the page level, the user technically can click anywhere, losing the focus on the controls. So I added the focusout event to detect that, and restore the
default page.

The problem is that if the user has the focus on one control, and clicks on another control, for a brief second the default help is shown. This is of course to be expected, since I am doing a focusout on one control (which displays the default help) followed by a focusin on the other control (which displays the help for that control).

How can I prevent the flickering? In other words, how do I check not really the focusin/out, but the focuschange, knowing from where I come from in the focus, and where I am going?

Comment: 1) Add a delay for the default content 2) Add a [mre] so we can try this for ourself.

Comment: I am not adding a minimal reproducible example involving R, shiny, javascript and css. Either you know the answer or don't bother writing it. @0stone0

Comment: Just trying to help since MRE's resolve in more and better answers by the community. Kinda easy to do tho for a 140k+ rep user. I'll remove it since there's already an answer that uses a delay.

Answer (score 1):

The code below effectively creates a "focus change" detection by using a delayed action on focusout and clearing that action if a new control receives focus quickly enough.

```
let helpTimeout;

function updateHelpTextForControl(controlId) {
    // Update the help text for the focused control
}

function setDefaultHelpText() {
    // Set the default help text
}

document.querySelectorAll('.control').forEach(control => {
    control.addEventListener('focusin', function() {
        // Clear any pending timeout to reset help text
        clearTimeout(helpTimeout);

        // Update the help text for this control
        updateHelpTextForControl(this.id);
    });

    control.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
        // Set a delay before resetting to the default help text
        helpTimeout = setTimeout(setDefaultHelpText, 100); // adjust delay as needed
    });
});
```

Comment: No one will provide a minimal example. Please stop asking for that. Is it some new policy? I am not writing a minimal example to extract from legally protected code a concoction of R, shiny, javascript and css. It will take me hours.

Comment: @StefanoBorini no problem. hopefully you can find some value in my response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event of `focusout` to check `e.relatedTarget?.nodeName` to see if the newly focus is an element which has a custom Help page.

Then instead of setting the default help, instantly set the new help of the new focus element.

```js
const i = document.querySelector('input');
i.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
    if (e.relatedTarget?.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        console.log('Lost focus, but got focus on other input, setting correct Help');
    } else {
        console.log('Lost focus, setting default help');
    }
})
```

```css
#left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id='left'>Foo</div>

<input id='a' />
<input id='b' />
```